# How do I aerate a small 3x5 meter pond without using any electricity

Tags: ponds

I am looking to build a small natural pond (no filters or pumps) in a polytunnel. The last step in designing this is the water aeration method. I've seen various options for solar-powered aeration devices but I'd like to aerate it in a completely natural way if possible.
Is this possible? 
If so how?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Can you please add why you want to aerate the water? What do you intend to do with it? Keep fish?

Comment: Aerate, you mean helping oxygen to dissolve in the water? Or just remove unwanted algae?

Comment: how deep is the pond? Goal of aeration, how much aeration do you need?

Comment: And while you are busy improving your question, add a link that explains *polytunnel* and address the question raised under Fred's answer.

Comment: @Jan Doggen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytunnel

Comment: How deep is it going to be. You might not need anything more than the wind passing through the tunnel.

Comment: The main purpose of the aeration is to stop water stratification, to create a healthy habitat for indigenous wildlife  .

Comment: This is an indoor pool, inside the polytunnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method that has been used to aerate water in larger water treatment plants is to [cascade the water](http://www.internationaljournalssrg.org/IJCE/2015/Special-Issue/NCRACCESS-2015/Part-2/IJCE-NCRACCESS-P106.pdf).

Depending on the amount of land available, you might be able to install a stepped cascade, prior to the water entering the main pond - see page 43 in the link.

Comment: How do you move the water through the cascade? That sound like it require a pump, which the OP did not want.

Comment: @kingledion: difference in elevation. The OP didn't state whether the ground was flat of not

Comment: I agree with Fred's answer. The best way to naturally provide aeration is to let water fall into the pond. If there are no suitable elevation differences,  a raised large rain barrel that slowly flows its contents into the pond could be an option.